# Disable/hide print and download button in iframe pdfviewer

Tags: jquery, angularjs

We have requirement to disable/hide print and download because there are personal document and should not be download or print. I am using angularjs1 and simple iframe tag to display PDF. I have tried many ways to do it using jquery and angular1 but it didn't work. Please help to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Assuming you're using the built-in PDF viewer now bundled with most browsers, you can't.

Comment: Yes I am using built-in PDF viewer

Comment: That is not possible. Moreover, user can just take a screenshot and save that personal document.